# Does the Linux kernel have knowledge of bind mounts?

Tags: linux, mount, bind-mount

I've been looking for a way to list bind mounts or at least determine if a particular mount is a bind mount. Several answers on this website say that because it is a parameter of a mount operation it will not appear in files like `/proc/mounts` or in the output of `mounts`. If the device node `/dev/sda1` is mounted at `/` and the directory `/etc` is bind mounted at `/etcetera`, then the output from mount will look like:

```
/dev/sda1 / <some other stuff>
/dev/sda1 /etcetera <some other stuff>
```

But the kernel must have some knowledge of a bind mount, otherwise it would not be able to bind one directory to another and keep a record of that particular directory being bound to some other directory. Any thoughts on this?

UPDATE: I am not asking about how to find bind mounts. I am asking how the kernel can possibly know about them.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not a duplicate. I'm asking about the kernel.

Comment: Please define what it means that the kernel knows about something.